# Plone memberdata update: PropertiesUpdatedEvent not triggered

Tags: python, events, event-handling, plone, zope

I'm trying to perform an action after the update of member properties on @@personal-information, but the event is not being fired. On configure.zcml I've put the following:

```
<subscriber
    for="Products.PluggableAuthService.interfaces.events.IPropertiesUpdatedEvent"
    handler=".subscribers.propertiesUpdated"
/>
```

I've already tried to use ipdb to check if propertiesUpdated of subscribers.py is being executed, but it's not.

I've checked the https://bugs.launchpad.net/zope-pas/+bug/795086 bug report, that says this bug has been fixed, but it's still not working.

I'm using PluggableAuthService 1.10.0.

Is there a better way to solve this issue?

Comment: The https://bugs.launchpad.net/zope-pas/+bug/795086 bug was about problems in the event itself not the fact that it's not fired. IMHO it's a new bug.

Comment: Might be the reason: https://dev.plone.org/ticket/13661 ?

Comment: I don't see [dev.plone.org/ticket/13661](https://dev.plone.org/ticket/13661) being related with this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PropertiesUpdated event (that implements IPropertiesUpdatedEvent) is not fired in Plone code (looked at Plone 4.3).

The only event that is fired once you change account info is `plone.app.controlpanel.events.ConfigurationChangedEvent`. You might want to subscribe to that event and filter (as this event is a generic event fired in a lot of places).

Something I do to know what events are fired after an action is just: I add a print statement in zope.event.notify (`print event, event.__dict__`) and start in foreground mode.

You might want to ask for an enhancement on https://dev.plone.org or better implement it. The plone.app.users package is a good place to start.